# navbar smaller than navbar-brand

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am looking for a way to have a bigger navbar-brand (bootstrap 4) than the height of the navbar itself. So the navbar-brand should overlap the navbar. Currently it seems that the navbar height is increased to fit the navbar-brand.

[image]

My HTML looks like:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom fixed-top top-menu-4">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x170.png" width="350px" height="170px" alt="">
        </div>
        <button class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive"
            aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="none.html">Example 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="none.html">Example 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="none.html">Example 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</nav>
```

So what I want is something like an overlap:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make the `navbar-brand` position:absolute...

```
.navbar-brand {
    top:0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/sJc3uCUL5s

Answer (score 0):

Give a fixed height to the .navbar and apply transform for .navbar-brand

```
.navbar {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255,255, 0.9);
}

.navbar-brand {
  transform: translateY(calc(50% - 30px));
}
```

[Find the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/264727/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height of the `.navbar` to some fixed value and since you're using flexbox on your `.container` you can align the `.nav-brand` element to the top of it.

See below for details:

```css
.navbar .container {
height: 100px; /* change this to whatever value you want */ 
}

.navbar-brand {
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom fixed-top top-menu-4">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x170.png" width="350px" height="170px" alt="">
        </div>
        <button class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive"
            aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="none.html">Example 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="none.html">Example 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="none.html">Example 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should apply absolute position on your image.

```
.navbar-brand img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 30px;
    max-height: 100px;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```